# Reflecting text in java

Tags: java, graphics

**I am trying to make  a digital clock in this way:**

As shown in the image 1 i want the clock to be **reflected**.

[image]

What i have tried:
I tried using java (Graphics2D)g by rotating the string and the using substring but i got this problem:

[image]

My code for this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DigitalClock extends JPanel {

JLabel label = new JLabel();
int c = 0;
Font font = null;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

//Constructor
public DigitalClock(){

    frame.setSize(700,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    DigitalThread();

}


//Paint Method
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

     //The background
     g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g2d.fillRect(0,0,500,100);

     //Show Time
     g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     g2d.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().toString(),10,15));
     g2d.drawString(timeNow(),100, 25);

     //Show time Reflected
     g2d.rotate(Math.PI,100,25);
     g2d.drawString(timeNowRot(timeNow()),45, 20);


}

//Change time Value with this Thread
 public void DigitalThread(){

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){

         boolean flag=true;
        while(flag==true){  
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        repaint();
        }

      }}).start();

  }  


 //Return time
 public String timeNow(){

   return  zero(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+
           zero(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+zero(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
 }

 //Return time reflected
 public String timeNowRot(String time){

     return   time.substring(time.length()-1,time.length())+time.substring(time.length()-2,time.length()-1)+":";
 }


 //Add Zero if value<10
 public String zero(int num){        
     if(num<10)  return "0"+num;    
     else  return ""+num;                
 }
```

}

I can achieve this by using java 2d? is there a method to rotate a string again vertically so i have not this problem thanks..

Comment: FYI I didn't seem to have permission to see the images you linked to

Comment: @sjr i will try to fix it

Comment: I got confused when reading the title. "reflection" and "string" are a little ambiguous here.

Comment: @howTo you can put images in by putting `!` in front of the link syntax, try to find the image url. This makes it easier to view.

Comment: If you are talking about reflection you need to scale on an axis with a negative value. For instance ```g2d.scale(1, -1);``` to invert the y axis.

Comment: You can see them now

Comment: @Ramón Gil Moreno i try to scale on y axis but scale not working for (1,-1)by [y] or (-1,1)by [x] why this happen?

Comment: By *not working* I assume you mean that nothing gets displayed. Note that your drawing coordinates will be inverted after the -1 scaling, so to draw at (x, y) on the screen you shall provide the (x, -y) coordinates to the ```drawString``` call. Is this what you observe?

Comment: @Ramón Gil Moreno Yes that was what i needed( found it yesterday althought thanks man)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found the answer based n your answers thanks all:

*It is and irony but the next day after the question i had a lesson at university about that...*

Info about **scaling**:

```
 g2d.scale(1,-1);  /*scale  by y axes(Flipping vertical
                                                             |
                                    flip here (scale(-1,1) ) |   here it was
                                                    _ _ _ _ _|_ _ _ _ _
                                                             |                                                                
                                   flip here (scale(-1,-1) ) |   fliped here( scale(1,-1) )
                                                             |  
                       */   
g2d.drawString(timeNow(),10,-27);
```

I also added some more effect so the clock be more realistic like:

```
 g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0,-15,color,0,-50,Color.BLACK));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [scale(x, y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale-double-double-) which multiplies the x and y coordinates.

```
g2d.scale(1.0, -1.0);
g2.drawString(....);
g2d.scale(1.0, -1.0); // Undo
```

This does a transformation where the y axis is reversed.
You could also use `shear` for a paralellogram look.

A `g2d.scale(-1.0, 1.0);` would draw the string backwards. Can be used in combination with the rotation.

It allt depends on the usage of any rotation and the order, how to scale. Without rotation: scale y by -1:

```
good
ƃooq
```

Comment: yes i need to rotate the string by y axis that's true. Can you provide a little bit more info ?

Comment: Actually sir is the a method to flip Horizontal a String for example "S" to be flipped horizontal like "ƨ" found this here  [http://txtn.us/mirror-words]?

Comment: I learned more about scaling and how it works on axes with (+ and - values).Scale works perfect for example (2,2) but not working for (-1,1) or (1,-1) even though i have a create a big panel to check the word ("good") why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your link shows a clock face AND its reflection. If that's what you want to do then this is the way.

Draw the clock face into an Image, instead of direct to the Component. Then you render the resulting image into the component twice using drawImage - once the normal way, and once transformed so it looks reflected.

This uses slightly more memory, but only temporarily, and it saves you having to do the paint twice.

If you only want to draw the reflected clock face, then set the image transformation properties in the Graphics to get the reflection.

I'll leave the details as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: No need to create an image. A transformation will be enough.

Comment: drawing an image it will cosume more ram or i am wrong?

Comment: @RamónGilMoreno I am assuming that the user wants to draw the clock and its reflection, which is what the illustration he linked to shows, in which case it's much more efficient to create an image than to do the entire rendering twice. If he only wants to do it once then yes, it's easier to do the transformation  in the Graphics.

Comment: @howTo There will be slightly more RAM used during the draw process, but unless it's a huge image it won't affect your total memory consumption much, and the RAM will be made available for garbage collection as soon as the paint is over.

Comment: @DJClayworth my actually problem is the image2  the letters are shown in different direction for example "3" is looking at different direction from the other "3" above is there a way to flip a letter horizontally in java that's what i need now... thanks for help