# Flip JavaFX Image horizontally or vertically

Tags: java, image, javafx, transformation

I am facing a problem flipping horizontally or vertically an Image in `JavaFX Canvas`.

Scale in theory:

```
  flip here (scale(-1,1) ) |   here it was
                  _ _ _ _ _|_ _ _ _ _
                           |                                                                
 flip here (scale(-1,-1) ) |   fliped here( scale(1,-1) )
```

Here are some lines of the method which is called about 30 times per second.So i am using the method `gc.scale(-1,0)` to flip the image horizontally but everything lags.How can i do that?

```
public void drawMethod{

  //....

  gc.drawImage(lightBlueLight, 0, 0); // where lightBlueLight is an `Image`


 //...
}
```

For example in `Swing` i was using this way to reflect text-> [Reflecting text in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623716/reflecting-text-in-java)

But in JavaFX i am new to transformations so i don't know what is the way to do this(if possible i want to know the best way it terms of cpu usage):

---

Sample image(what i have):

[image]

i want to draw it on canvas as:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void draw(GraphicsContext g){
     //(javafx.scene.image.Image, 
     // sourceX,sourceY, sourceWidth,sourceHeight,
    //outputX,outputY,outputWidth,outputHeight);        
    g.drawImage(RESOURCE, 0, 0, RESOURCE.getWidth(), RESOURCE.getHeight(), RESOURCE.getWidth(),0,-RESOURCE.getWidth(),RESOURCE.getHeight());
}
```

by inputting **negative value as output width/height value** will flip the image. (remember to adjust your output X and Y accordingly)
I run the code with 30 fps,it runs smoothly.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yPnP.jpg)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-

Comment: I will have a look ☺ I need at least 60 fps.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to a scale, you also need a translate otherwise it will just flip around the left edge of the canvas and show nothing.

[image: fipped]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Flipper extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        Image image = new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySbuj.png");
        double xoff = 15;
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.save();
        gc.translate(image.getWidth() + xoff * 2, 0);
        gc.scale(-1, 1);
        gc.drawImage(image, xoff, 0);
        gc.restore();
        gc.drawImage(image, xoff, 0);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(canvas)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jewelsea i  assume that it fits for 60 fps... The concept of `gc.save();` i think it is slow.

Comment: [`gc.save()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#save--) just sticks some attributes on the stack.  It is an operation that will execute extremely quickly and have no significant impact on animated fps.

Comment: Thank you jewelsea  . I choosed the second answer cause it is very simple and 1 line :)